# MySQL constraint to ensure data integrity between two tables (1-n cardinality)

Tags: mysql, integrity

I made a minimal example to describe my problem using the concept of player using items in a game (which makes my problem easier to understand).

My problematic is the following. Let's say I have to store items and the player holding them in my database.

[image]

I didn't show it on the image but a player could hold no item but it's really important for my problem.

I translated that into :

[image]

Which gives the two following tables (with PK_ and #FK) :

[image]

In my example I can then fill them as such :

[image]

By doing :

[image]

Now, I want any player to have a "favorite" item, so I want to add a foreign key #item_id in the table Player but I want to make sure this new value refers to an item being hold by the right player in the Item table. How can I add a (check?) constraint to my table declarations so that condition is always true to ensure data integrity between my two tables? I don't think I can solve this by creating a third table since it's still a 1n cardinality. Also I don't want to ALTER the table I want to CREATE, since my database is not yet to be deployed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your SQL queries as text, not as images, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056

Comment: just alter one of the tables to add the fk constraint after creating both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a third table which links the `player` and `item` table for the favorite item for each player (if you don't want a cycle reference between `player` and `item`). There are two restrictions to solve:

1. A player must own the item, they want to have as a favorite.
2. A player can have only one favorite item.

The first point can be solved with a multi-column foreign key. The table `item` needs an index for the `playerId` and the `id` of the item. Then your new table for the favorite items can reference this index as a foreign key. The inclusion of the `playerId` in the foreign key ensures that the item isn't "moved" to a different player while it is marked as favorite. The queries will look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE item(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    playerId INT NOT NULL,
    INDEX item_id_and_playerId (playerId, id)
);

CREATE TABLE favItem(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    playerId INT NOT NULL,
    itemId INT NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY favItem_FQ_id_and_playerId (playerId, itemId) REFERENCES item(playerId, id)
);
```

The second point can be solved by a simple `UNIQUE` constraint on the `playerId` column of the new favorite items table. That way only one item can be marked as favorite. We adjust the `CREATE TABLE` query for the `favItem` table as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE favItem(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    playerId INT NOT NULL,
    itemId INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY favItem_FQ_id_and_playerId (playerId, itemId) REFERENCES item(playerId, id),
    CONSTRAINT favItem_UQ_playerId UNIQUE (playerId)
);
```

See the following queries how they work:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM player;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM item;
+----+----------+
| id | playerId |
+----+----------+
|  1 |        1 |
|  2 |        1 |
|  3 |        2 |
|  4 |        3 |
|  5 |        3 |
|  6 |        3 |
+----+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO favItem(playerId, itemId) VALUES (1, 2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO favItem(playerId, itemId) VALUES (3, 2);
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
    (`test`.`favItem`, CONSTRAINT `favItem_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
    (`playerId`, `itemId`) REFERENCES `item` (`playerId`, `id`))
mysql> INSERT INTO favItem(playerId, itemId) VALUES (1, 1);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'favItem.favItem_UQ_playerId'
```

The first row can be added without problem. However, the second row can't be added because the player with the id `playerId=3` does not "own" the item with the id `itemId=2`. The third row can't be added either because the player with the id `playerId=1` cannot mark the item with the id `itemId=1` (which he owns) as a favorite because of the UNIQUE constraint on `playerId`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `isFavorite` column in the `Item` table. It's value is either `NULL` or a predefined value, like a `ENUM` value. Then you can add a `UNIQUE` constraint over the two columns `playerId` and `isFavorite`. That way, a player can have only one `item` as favorite, since multiple rows with the same `playerId` and `isFavorite` value would result in a unique constraint error. The table can look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE items(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    playerId INT NOT NULL,
    isFavorite ENUM('FAV') NULL,
    CONSTRAINT items_UQ_fav UNIQUE (PlayerId, isFavorite)
);
```

Check the following queries how a new row would validate the unique constraint:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO
    items(playerId, isFavorite)
VALUES
    (4, NULL), (7, NULL), (7, 'FAV'), (5, 'FAV');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM items;
+----+----------+------------+
| id | playerId | isFavorite |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 |        4 | NULL       |
|  4 |        5 | FAV        |
|  2 |        7 | NULL       |
|  3 |        7 | FAV        |
+----+----------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO items(playerId, isFavorite) VALUES (5, 'FAV');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '5-FAV' for key 'items.items_UQ_fav'
```